# Xelatex not giving me my font

Tags: xetex

I'm using pandoc to export to PDF via xelatex. I have the template properly set up -- or at least it was last time I backed it up, which was before I reinstalled Linux. I then had to reinstall xelatex and fontspec, but I think things are back to where I had them. But, when I try to run pandoc, I get...

```
pandoc: Error producing PDF from TeX source.  
! Font EU1/lmr/m/n/10=[lmroman10-regular]:mapping=tex-text at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or installed font not found.  
<to be read again>  
               relax   
l.100 \fontencoding\encodingdefault\selectfont
```

My template calls for Liberation Serif, not lmroman, and I can't find where lmroman is called. I get that the error is caused by not having lmroman installed, but the real question is why it's not using Liberation Serif.

Comment: ...export markdown to PDF...

Comment: Latin Modern is the defaultif no other font is set with fontspec. Are you sure you still have Liberation Serif on your system after you reinstalled?

Comment: Yes, I have all the Liberation variants, serif, sans, and mono.

Comment: As I don't know pandoc, it's hard to say. Just in case: add to your preamble `\setmainfont{Liberation Serif}`.

Comment: As I understand these things, the template acts as the preamble to the document, and it already contains...

    \setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Liberation Serif}
    \setromanfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Liberation Serif}

Comment: As latin modern is the default font, you should really find out why it is not working.

Comment: Good observation, Ulrike Fischer. I installed the lm-fonts package, and stopped getting that error. Of course, now I'm getting different errors. I'll be back if I can't fix them.

Comment: Could you post (a link to) the template?

Comment: Note that currently the recommended syntax is `\setmainfont{<name of font>}[<options>]`. I have no idea why `fontspec` reverses the expected order of optional and required arguments, but it does. (The deprecated syntax should still work, as I understand things. And you probably have an older version of TeX Live anyway. So I don't think this is the cause of your problems.)

Comment: As a sanity check, what does `fc-match "Liberation Serif"` return?

Comment: steve@office ~ $ fc-match "Liberation Serif"
LiberationSerif-Regular.ttf: "Liberation Serif" "Regular"

Comment: Very strange. With Latin Modern installed, it exports correctly... with Liberation Serif used. It doesn't make sense, but I'm not complaining. Thanks for the insights!

Comment: I saw this error on Ubuntu 14.04. Installing the `texlive-fonts-recommended` package fixed it. https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/2206